# ignite: how to delete created ML datasets from db/work folder after trained the model

Tags: machine-learning, ignite

Following is the piece of code using to build the model. Trainer class creating data-sets across the cluster while during the training, once model was build, i want delete those created data-sets from the work folder.

Why it is not removing from work folder? is there any way to call auto closeable explicitly?

```
IgniteCache<Integer, double[]> dataCache = createCacheBasedData(ignite, rows, cacheName);

KMeansTrainer trainer = new KMeansTrainer()
    .withDistance(distanceMeasure)  //other metrics are HammingDistance, ManhattanDistance
    .withAmountOfClusters(k) // number of clusters want to create
    .withMaxIterations(maxIterations)
    .withEpsilon(1.0E-4D)
    .withSeed(seed);

Model mdl = trainer.fit(
    ignite,
    dataCache,
    modelData.getTrainData(),
    modelData.getFeatureExtractor(),
    modelData.getLabelExtractor()
);

dataCache.destory();
```

Answer (score 1):

What files remain after training completion? What cache config do you use? K-Means explicitly uses try-with-resources on CacheBasedDataset and close() calling for this type of dataset explicitly destroy auxiliary caches and data.